# UI-specific values in ViewModel

Tags: wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

Is it wrong to use UI-specific values like `System.Windows.ResizeMode` or `System.Windows.WindowState` in `ViewModel`? I am using *Caliburn.Micro's WindowManager*, which have dictionary of view settings in `ShowWindow` method. I don't know any other (simple) method of setting window properties other than this.

```
Imports Caliburn.Micro
Namespace ViewModels
  Public Class MainWindowViewModel
    Inherits PropertyChangedBase
    Private _windowManager As IWindowManager
    Sub New(windowManager As IWindowManager)
      _windowManager = windowManager
    End Sub
    Sub ShowUserControl()
      Dim windowSettings As New Dictionary(Of String, Object)
      windowSettings.Add("ResizeMode", ResizeMode.NoResize)
      _windowManager.ShowDialog(New UserControl1ViewModel, settings:=windowSettings)
    End Sub
  End Class
End Namespace
```

Comment: Will it work if you define them in `ViewModel`? I think you need to have them defined before instancing `ShowWindow()`, `ShowDialog()` or `ShowPopup()` in `WindowManager`.

Comment: Everything works as it should. My question is if it is correct or not to use these values from UI layer in ViewModels or in other words, if it breaks MVVM rules.

Comment: As I see, this is not connected with `MVVM`. This is purely UI requirement, and while it doesn't affect business logic, it will not break `MVVM` rules.

Comment: In pure MVVM, nothing concerning UI (including content of WPF libraries) should not be present in ViewModels.

Comment: Well yes, and still not... your `VM` still doesn't work with any of your elements. The only time I see when it would break the MVVM is when calling `GetView();` (C# background)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it wrong to use UI-specific values like System.Windows.ResizeMode or System.Windows.WindowState in ViewModel?

Not really. This doesn't break the MVVM pattern. A view model is a model of the view. Whether it is an issue or not mainly depends on whether you are sharing your view model classes across several different types of client applications, like for example a WPF desktop application and a Xamarin mobile app.

In this case you should prefer to expose primitive types from the view models and then use converters in each specific type of client app to convert between the view model type and the corresponding view type.

But in theory and as far as MVVM is concerned, a view model doesn't have to be agnostic of the UI technology on which the view is built.

Comment: Fortunately it is only WPF application and it will not be ported to other platforms.